# how to check if a number starts with two allowed numbers php?

Tags: php

How to validate that the numeric string starts the first two numbers only with the following list allowed:

`01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, and 30.`

```
$number = 1234567890;

if(ctype_digit($number)){
    if (strlen($number) <= 10) {
        echo "The registered number is correct";
    } else {
        echo "The number must have 10 digits";
    }
} else {
    echo "Number must be digit / numeric only.";
}
```

What I want to add to this functionality is to validate that said number that is stored in `$number` must start with the first two numbers that are in the list in order to continue.

Comment: How can a PHP integer start with `0`?  Are the inputs you have _numbers_ or are they _strings_ ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hello, the purpose of my code is that it is only numeric and that it must have a total of 10 digits and finally that it must start with the first two numbers already mentioned.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all `:-(`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, they must be numerical but since the code is like this: `$number = 1234567890;` or like this `$number = "1234567890";` my code is validating both without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to temporarily cast the number into a string and make use of the regular expression of `^([01]\d|2[0-4]|30)` to check whether the number string starts with the specific values you mentioned in the above. You can use PHP's [`preg_match` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to help check whether the string matches the regular expression.

So your code becomes:

```
if(ctype_digit($number)){
   if (strlen($number) <= 10 and preg_match('/^([01]\d|2[0-4]|30)/', (string)$number)) {
       echo "The registered number is correct";
   } else {
       echo "The number must have 10 digits or it begins with incorrect values";
   }
} else {
   echo "Number must be digit / numeric only.";
}
```

Regular expression explanation:

- `^`: Matches the pattern from the start of the string
- `[01]\d`: Matches `00`, `01`, `02`, ... , `10`, `11`, ... , `19`
- `2[0-4]`: Matches `20`, `21`, ... , `24`
- `30`: Matches `30`
- `([01]\d|2[0-4]|30)`: Match either `[01]\d`, `2[0-4]` or `30`

`preg_match` function returns `1` if the regular expression pattern is matched successfully.

Comment: if I add the data like this: `$number= 0162323112;` show me this message: `Number must be digit / numeric only.` and if it's like this: `$number= "0162323112";` show me this message: `The registered number is correct`. Is it normal for this to happen?

Comment: PHP will ignore any zeros put at the very front of a numeric value, so PHP will read `0162323112` as`162323112`, and then cast this number into a string. If it's necessary to store numeric values that starts with zeros, you can consider changing the data type `$number` into a string

Comment: @AnsonH No, this is not true, it won't "ignore leading zeros", it will interpret it as an octal number, converting it to a different number altogether. There's a link in my answer to the php manual where this is explained, and here is [a sample](https://3v4l.org/G7LCE) where you can verify it.

Comment: CC @Valentina on my previous comment. If you rely on leading zeros being ignored you'll get incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

If your allowed starting numbers are stored in an array, you could extract the 2 first numbers from `$number` using `substr()` and then check with `in_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) for this, but something to note: a number starting with a `0` will be interpreted as [`octal`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.syntax) and converted to base 10. To avoid this, you must quote the number:

```
$number = '055231';

// Fill the list of allowed numbers
$allowed = array_map(function($number) { 
    // Fill each element to length 2 with '0' to the left
    return str_pad($number, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); 
}, range(1, 24));
$allowed[] = 30;

if (preg_match('/^\d{2,10}$/', $number)) {
    // At this point we know it contains only numbers
    // Extract first two characters
    $start = substr($number, 0, 2);
   
    // Check if it's in the allowed list
    if (in_array($start, $allowed)) {
        echo "The registered number is correct";
    } else {
        echo "The number is incorrect";
    }
} else {
    echo "Number must be digit / numeric only.";
}
```

Regex breakdown:

- `^` and `$` are delimiters. The string must match exactly.
- `\d`. Digit character class. Matches only numbers.
- `{2,10}`. Previous group must be of length between 2 and 10 (since it must start with two digits).

Function reference:

- [`range`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)
- [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [`str_pad`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)
- [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr)

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternate solution could be to hardcode the valid prefixes and check if the first 2 characters of the string is one of them using **[array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)**:

```
$valid_prefixes = array_fill_keys(array("01", "02", "03", "04", "05",
                                        "06", "07", "08", "09", "10",
                                        "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
                                        "16", "17", "18", "19", "20",
                                        "21", "22", "23", "24", "30"), true);

function starts_with_valid_prefix($str) {
  global $valid_prefixes;
  return strlen($str) >= 2 && array_key_exists(substr($str, 0, 2), $valid_prefixes);
}
```